# Can't get sound to work when connecting Airpods Pro (Second Generation) to bluetooth in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 22.10

I am using Ubuntu 22.10 and I am able to successfully pair Apple AirPods Pro (2nd Generation) via Bluetooth. However, I cannot get sound to work once connected. I know they are paired correctly because The AirPods do seem to be able to control the volume of the system. I am able to adjust the volume using the stem-swipe gesture but no sound passes through the device.

I do notice I get a split second of sound when I change the configuration option for Output in the Sound Settings but it does not last.

I also noticed I can get sound out of the left earbud if I reset the Airpods Pro (2nd Gen) and re-pair them (by holding the pair button on the back of the Airpods until the light in the front turns orange). This will work momentarily (for one earbud) but re-connecting the Airpods or changing the output profile in soud settings makes them no longer work (either ear)

For what it's worth, Sound on the older AirPods Pro (1st Generation) seems to work just fine.

Has anybody else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Switch from Pipewire to Pulse audio and its gonna work just fine

Answer (score 0):

I asked on [launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/705677) about a similar issue.

Basically pipewire is missing some [codecs](https://launchpad.net/%7Eaglasgall/+archive/ubuntu/pipewire-extra-bt-codecs) by default, installing them did the trick !

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aglasgall/pipewire-extra-bt-codecs
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).